# MSP Busbar rating and Max branch circuit breaker for PV solar on Sq.D Meter mains CSED SC816D200C series 2

Tags: electrical-panel, solar

Existing Sq.D SC816D200C series 2 CSED.
200A main service disconnect breaker.

What is the Busbar rating?

I am upgrading solar to a 7.5kW system and all solar (PV & battery)
will require a 60A breaker. But NEC 705.12 BACKFEED ALLOWED implies I'm limited depending on bus bar rating.

If busbar is 200A looks like I have to derate main breaker to 175A.

Also I am a bit dumbfounded by the Schneider, everywhere I searched, the results indicated all breakers are limited to 70A max.
But ... Found at Schneider.com, the product data sheet for this meter main. On page 4 the last two sentences say "A 100A Max. circuit breaker may be installed in the lowest position in the branch panel. All other positions are limited to 70A max. circuit breakers."

Anyone have confirmation of busbar and the 100A breaker?

Comment: I think it depends on the panel.  Most panels it is recommended to have large breakers close to the main breaker.  I think to not have high amps passing by small breakers.  If the panel lists/labels that location for 100 amps then you must use that location.  The bus bar might be 200amps, but a 100 is half of that.

Answer (score 1):

Unless they've changed the multiplication tables, 7.5 kW solar divided by 240V is only 31.3 amps.

This is a solar-ready HOM ranch/trailer panel (Meter + main + 8 breaker spaces + thru lugs), and "solar-ready" means an additional breaker space on the meter side of the main, intended for solar.

The solar breaker appears to have a 50A max capacity, but that's not very useful if you're doing a battery system.

The labeling would give the last word, but the literature I could find plainly says you have 200A internal busing.  Some companies use 225A buses on their 200A panels, but HOMeline's whole format is to be the cheapest one in the store, so they cost-shave pretty relentlessly.

200A x the 120% rule gives 240A, and with a 200A main breaker solar is limited to 40A.  However you are at 31.3 amps so you should be fine.

Comment: Solar is a bit more complicated. two circuits ea. at 20A => 40A and battery at 20A => so at 60A. Found a vid at Sq. D that says look at box label. The box label (pulled cover of breaker panel) and it indicates "Mains 250A Max." so that I believe imply 250A busbar, is that correct?